# Adjust indents in QTableWidget cells and header items

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I would like to align texts in a `QTableWidget` on the left side, but I would also like to add an indent so the text isn't stuck against the border. On the image, `col_2` is what I want. And I would like the same for the header labels.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        entries = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee']
        for row, form in enumerate(entries):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
            for column, item in enumerate(form):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['col_1', 'col_2'])

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the indents, the [QSS Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) suggests that it should be possible to use the [QTableWidget::item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#item-sub) and [QHeaderView::section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#section-sub) selectors:

```
self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("""
    QTableWidget::item {padding-left: 5px; border: 0px}
    """)

self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet("""
    QHeaderView::section {padding-left: 5px; border: 0px}
    """)
```

However, I tried all the various combinations of padding, margin and border settings, and found that they either don't work at all, or have weird and ugly side-effects. After looking at several similar questions on SO and elsewhere, it seems that the exact behaviour of these stylesheet settings depends on what plaform you are on and/or what widget-style you are using. Hopefully they will work okay for you, but don't be surprised if you find a few glitches.

If the stylesheet solution doesn't work out, most people use a custom item-delegate. This usually involves reimplementing the [paint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) method. However, an alternative approach would be to reimplement the [displayText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#displayText) method and pad the returned text with spaces. This does not affect the underlying data at all, and gives completely equivalent results in a much simpler way. It is also quite simple to reimplement the [createEditor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) method so that the left margin is adjusted when editing cells. The complete custom item-delegate would then look like this:

```
class PaddingDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, padding=1, parent=None):
        super(PaddingDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self._padding = ' ' * max(1, padding)

    def displayText(self, text, locale):
        return self._padding + text

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        margins = editor.textMargins()
        padding = editor.fontMetrics().width(self._padding) + 1
        margins.setLeft(margins.left() + padding)
        editor.setTextMargins(margins)
        return editor
```

and it can be used like this:

```
self.delegate = PaddingDelegate()
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
```

The final piece of the puzzle is the indent for the header items. For this, it would seem simplest to just add some spaces to the label text:

```
self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([' col_1', ' col_2'])
```

And the alignment of the header labels can be set like this:

```
self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(
    QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```