# Changing the spacing between QTableView cells using stylesheet in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview, qtstylesheets

How to add spaces between table cells using QSS selectors. I've tried the border-spacing selector, the item pseudo-class with the border selector, but it all doesn't work as it should.

Here is a sample code that I thought was supposed to do this.

```
app. setStyleSheet ("QTableView { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 20px; color: red;}")
```

Here's a picture of what I mean.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkRBT.png]

Answer (score 1):

With style-sheets, you are either able to separate the individual cells via border-spacing (as in your example), or via padding:

```
app.setStyleSheet("QTableView::item { border:0px; padding: 150px; }")
```

Comment: when I do this, the margins appear for the entire table, not for each element

Comment: paddings*. Help please

Comment: yes, you are right, i was missing an ::item descriptor (updated my answer accordingly). However, this does not seem to work. Maybe this question helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750178/adjust-indents-in-qtablewidget-cells-and-header-items